# Is it possible to use main method in JUnit?

Tags: junit, jmeter

When I used the main method it return an error message.
Is it possible to run Taurus and converted it to JMX file using the main() method?
or It's compulsory to use JUnit and its annotation in my selenium script when it runs using Taurus tools and then want to convert to jmx.

Answer (score 0):

All supported modules are listed under [Selenium Executor](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Selenium/#Selenium-Executor) page of Taurus user manual.

`selenium` is a **virtual** executor, the "real" executors are:

- JUnit (Java)
- TestNG (Java)
- Apiritif (Python)
- PyTest (Python)
- RSpec (Ruby)
- Mocha (JavaScript)
- NUnit (C#)
- xUnit (C#)

In your case you need to comply with [JUnit executor](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JUnit/) features and limitations, to wit Taurus will only look for methods which are properly [annotated](https://mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-1-basic-usage/) which is not the case for `main()`

If you cannot or don't want to refactor your existing Selenium scripts code you can just set them to use [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder) as the [proxy for the browser](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/shared/#proxy) (by the way this is exactly what is Taurus doing under the hood of [Proxy2JMX Converter module](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Proxy2JMX/)